# Spring boot app recouse is not found when docarize

Tags: spring-boot, docker, resources

My app works fine from the IDE. But when I docarize the app, it can't find the applicaiton resoruce. How to docarize the app correctly that I can access resocur folder. Here is my code:-

Dockerfile

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /app
COPY target/Toolkit-*.jar /app/toolkit.jar
WORKDIR /app/
ENTRYPOINT java -jar toolkit.jar
```

I am reading propety as this:

```
@Log
public class PropertyLoader {

    private static String RESOURCE_FILENAME = "application.properties";
    private static PropertyLoader instance;
    private Properties properties;


    private PropertyLoader() {
           // works fine form IDE. Docker inputStream is null
            try (InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(RESOURCE_FILENAME)) { 
                properties = new Properties();
                properties.load(inputStream);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
            }
    }
}
```

How do I read application resorces in docker continaer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to application.properties to the image as well. add this to your Dockerfile

```
RUN mkdir -p /app/config
COPY <your file> /app/config/application.properties
```